# ffmpeg convert stereo to mono for multiple video files

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder of video files listing:

1H.mp4;
1L.mp4;
2H.mp4;
2L.mp4;
....

The sounds are unbalanced for two ears - it is probably due to the recording is stereo.  How can I change the audio tracks from stereo to mono for all the video files?

I assume the workflow would be extract (copy) the audio tracks out, change to mono, then insert (copy) back. I have found codes for individual files, but with hundreds of such short mp4 files, I'd like to know if I can use a 'loop' to deal with them all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No need to extract, you can downmix two audio channels and keep video channel and generate a new file in one command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -ac 1 mono-output.mp4
```

Here `-ac 1` says 1 audio channel, downmixed from stereo, look in [ffmpeg docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation).
Now make a loop. Assuming you are using bash or similar unix shell

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i $i -c:v copy -ac 1  mono-$i; done
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without re-encoding the audio? (I assume not, ∵ lossy stereo codecs are a single stream.)

Comment: @Geremia it is not re encoded, the stream is simply copied